# How do you organize your bundles in Symfony2 projects?

Tags: php, symfony, bundles

I have the exact question that this guy has: http://groups.google.com/group/symfony2/browse_thread/thread/cd35132cc6972f29

I'll just copy-paste it here:

> I was wondering what different ways of organizing bundles within a
>   project people are using.
>
> I seem to end up with either one massive bundle for a project or a lot
>   of bundles which are closely related (dependant) to each other. eg;
>
> I implemented my own user entity and login forms etc, but the users
>   are linked to an organization (with some functionality). Etc ... It's
>   mostly the entities that overlap a lot I guess ...
>
> Do you guys split them up or dump them all in the same bundle?

Comment: This seems like it could lead to being a "discussion question". Also, lots of answers are equally valid here without some concrete example of the problem. Different combinations of entities could change the answer for instance: `User` and `Organisation` (assuming there are other dependencies on Organisation within the system) - Different bundles. `BlogPost` and `BlogPostRevision` - Same bundle. It's partly intuition based on the design of the system - a bundle should just encapsulate some functionality which you consider to be cohesive.

Answer (score 15):

**Edit**: [I *don't* use bundles for app-specific code anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999433/should-everything-really-be-a-bundle-in-symfony-2).

---

Personally I prefer to have a bundle per a section of an application. For example:

- UserBundle
- BlogBundle
- ForumBundle
- JobBundle
- StoreBundle
- etc

This is okay if the app is a mishmash of several functionalities, none of which is big enough to require a separate application and/or a subdomain. But if I was developing a big webstore applicaton, my bundles would be more specific:

- UserBundle
- ProductBundle
- CartBundle
- SearchBundle
- WishlistBundle
- etc

So, I'd say, it depends on the focus of the project. What's just a section for one project could be the core functionality of another.

And I usually have *CommonBundle*, where all the common stuff goes, like global CSS, images, layouts, etc.

Also there are at least two options for the backend organization:

1. each bundle has its own backend section, or
2. there is one big backend bundle.

Personally I lean towards the first option and you can read about it in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8016867/745188), but there are people who prefer to have a separate bundle for the whole backend — probably using one of the [admin bundles](http://knpbundles.com/search?q=admin).

By the way, it's perfectly okay for bundles to be interconnected — you don't have to make them all independent of each other. For example, [JMSDiExtraBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle) depends on the [metadata](https://github.com/schmittjoh/metadata) library and [JMSAopBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSAopBundle), which in turn depends on [cg-library](https://github.com/schmittjoh/cg-library). If you'll try to keep bundles totally independent, you'll end up with big monolithic one-bundle lumps of code.

Answer (score 6):

For every project I start off with one CoreBundle, where I put everything together. Then I just develop features in it and as time goes I reevaluate it - if I might use this feature somewhere else someday (or even release to open source), I move it to a new bundle.

"Size" of the feature worth separate bundle doesn't really matter - I've seen OS bundles as big as a 1 single js file :D

One thing for sure - stuffing everything in a single bundle is bad, it goes against the whole reason why this architecture was implemented in the first place!

Comment: I am also starting using CoreBundle, unless the project is not big we don't need to create so many bundles... :)
+1

Answer (score 0):

My answer in the following topic can probably help you : [Symfony 2 : Location of Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353303/symfony-2-location-of-entities/8353626#8353626)

I'm not a Symfony2 master, but I think I have quite a good idea of the bundle design ; of course, there is no universal answer but you can follow some "best practices".

First of all, I don't think that big bundles are a good solution ; you doesn't split your project into applications anymore, like you did with Symfony1.4. You may ask "but what can I do with the frontend/backend logic ?" ; quite easy, use the controller !

Each bundle should refer to a module, a stone in your project's wall. You have to divide your application ; many bundles are not bad. Of course, don't do a bundle for each entities, that would be a waste of time. But imagine a blog application : you would have an User bundle, Articles bundle (which would manage posts, categories, ...), eventually a bundle for static pages, ...

It's not unlogical that your bundle are linked ; you are building a whole application, so in this case they are linked. But the keyword here is "generalization" ; your bundle should be able to be linked to others bundle, not only yours. You should be able to re-use it in others projects.

Good luck !